# Laravel running on an existing Ubuntu Web Server

Tags: php, laravel, apache, ubuntu

So I am setting up a laravel project on my existing Ubuntu Dev server. (So I won't need to run php artisan serve)

I managed to make it work by renaming server.php to index.php and copied the htaccess from public to project root.

However I am concerned if this might create a security issue? Is there a better way how to do this?
I believe This would also apply once the app is deployed to a live server.
Any feedback would be appreciated!

EDIT:
This is for development environment only as in my /var/www I have other projects not related to laravel and cannot change apache's virtual host to point to this laravel project. (Basically I need to run laravel in a subdirectory)

Comment: You should keep Laravel's original folder structure and make sure that you've configured the web servers document root to be the public folder, not the project root. That's how Laravel is intended to be run so that would be the "better way". It's never a good idea to make all files and folders accessible from outside, specially not when the application isn't meant to run like that.

Comment: In my dev environment I have a lot of other php projects, and its on a dedicated ubuntu machine. so in /var/www I have other projects not related to this one and with that said I cannot change apache's document root. What would be the best way to configure a dev environment in this case?

Comment: You can host multiple different sites with different document roots on the same Apache instance. Just create different vhosts for each project, giving them a separate domains (or sub domains). You asked for a better way, that is a better way. If that, for some reason, isn't acceptable, then you can always create an [alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html) for each site (and keep them in different folders outside of the main document root but you still set the alias document root to be the public folder).

Comment: Ok makes sense I got it. Thanks Magnus!